# Having issue with jquery .hover and map on Firefox

Tags: jquery

I'm having a problem using the jQuery .hover with a US Map on Firefox. What is happening is when you hover over the states, it seems that the .hover gets stuck, and no mouseenter events fire. Sometimes it will start working again and then stop.

I have setup an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mcanada/QXcxp/24) so that you can see a demonstration of what I'm trying to do.

If you just move the mouse around, a small div should pop up showing the state name. You should notice at some point while moving the mouse around that it stops updating the div. If you move outside the map and back in, it starts working again.

I'm sure my js code is not proper, but just need help with this.

CSS:

```
#popupdiv {
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    visibility: hidden;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#ImageMap').hover(function (event) {
     var left = event.pageX;
     var top = event.pageY;
     if (event.type == "mouseenter") {
         $("#popupdiv").html("This is "+event.target.title);
         scrh = $(window).height();
         scrw = $(window).width();
         divh = $("#popupdiv").height();
         divw = $("#popupdiv").width();
         $("#popupdiv").css({
             position: 'absolute',
             top: top,
             left: left,
             visibility: 'visible'
         });
     } else {
         $("#popupdiv").css("visibility", "hidden");
     }
   });
});
```

P.S. I didn't post the html here because it is long, but in the jsfiddle example.

Thank you all!

Comment: Looks fine to me. I've been hovering for about a minute and no problems have been seen.

Comment: I modified the link for a different revision. If you notice when you hover over the states, it pops up a div "This is state". What you might have seen before was the Title of the link.

Answer (score 0):

### Hypothesis:

I believe the issue here is that you are using the hover event. Hover means that you have entered the specified element. This will be fired once when the mouse enters, and not again until the mouse has left and then re-entered the element. Obviously your map cannot cover the entirety of the USA map there (there are "holes" of coverage). This I believe is why your div seems to appear erratically. When the mouse cursor leaves the coordinates covered by the map, then the hover event is free to fire again.

So for example you hover over Texas, and then when you go to hover over Oklahoma, you happen to never leave coordinates covered by the image map meaning that the hover event does not fire again. Then you move your mouse outside the map, and then when you re-enter it seemingly works again. This can also happen in between states where there are holes of coverage.

Please note that this is just a hypothesis as I am not super familiar with coordinate mapping in HTML, and this is obviously a fairly complicated one.

### Possible Solution:

I believe that you should instead add an event to watch for mouse movement. Then proceed to check whether the mouse is located in the image map, and if so show the specified image title.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and option. The strange thing is that if you do this with IE (I am using IE 10), it reacts exactly the way I would expect. Firefox is the only one that seems to have this problem. I have not tried Chrome.

Comment: @user1591297 You can see that Edward implemented my advice above and it does indeed seem to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is how the hover events are fired, `mouseenter` is not fired for sure after a `moueleave` and so on.

I tried to change the approach and use [`mousemove`](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/) event instead.

To avoid div flickering in mousemove I save the current showed state `currid`, and check if it's the same before showing it and it seems to work pretty well.

Code:

```
var data;
var hblock = [];
var stateid;
var currid = -1;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ImageMap').mousemove(function (event) {
        var left = event.pageX;
        var top = event.pageY;
        if (currid != event.target.id) {
            $("#popupdiv").css("visibility", "hidden");
            $("#popupdiv").html("This is " + event.target.title);
            scrh = $(window).height();
            scrw = $(window).width();
            divh = $("#popupdiv").height();
            divw = $("#popupdiv").width();
            $("#popupdiv").css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: top,
                left: left,
                visibility: 'visible'
            });
            stateid = event.target.id;
            currid = stateid;
        }  
    })
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/tUCSF/

Comment: Thank you Edward. By doing that, it seems to have fixed the problem I was having. With your jsfiddle example, I can hover over every state (slow and fast) and the div updates just like it should. Since the code was not making that check, it may have been getting itself all tangled up!

Comment: If the answer solves your problem consider to accept it using the green mark near it (for destails see the FAQ)